# Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler Error While Add/Disable a Task

Tags: services, chkdsk, windows-task-scheduler

When I try disable a existing task or add a new task, the following error appears.

```
Transaction support within the specified file system resource manager is not started or was shutdown due to an error. <task-name>
```

---

Then I read the MS Support, they recommends run the fsutil like this:

```
fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\
```

But when I try run this command I get the following error message:

```
Error: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

---

Finally when I try to check disk (chkdsk command), the system says:

```
1304 large file records processed.
File record segment 119470 is an orphan.

Errors found. CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode.
```

---

I couldn't disable the task, briefly. How can I fix this task scheduler (or what else) error?

Comment: Use `chkdsk /f` and then see if it helps.

Comment: it doesn't help. There is no change.